# Seeking sample MS Outlook web add-in (no Visual studio)

Tags: outlook

I am a professional embedded software developer. I have some self taught web skills, with PHP & AngularJs 1.x.

Now, I am trying to develop an MS Outlook web add-in. I want it to be an angular JS app, without using MS Visual Studio. I plan to add a button to the tool bar, and invoking it will start an Angular app (which I have already coded & tested) as an asynch dialog (using `displayDialogAsync()`).

Sounds simple, huh? Just drop the existing app into a web add-in skeleton.

I have spent my evenings and weekends for several weeks now, following one tutorial after another, and am still getting nowhere.

What am I look for is an MS Outlook web add-in (not using Visual Studio)
with an Synch Dialog, (not message read, which what most of the examples are for, or even message compose - an aynch dialog); it should add a button to the button bar to launch my dialog, which contains my AngularJs app.

When the app launches, an `alert("Hello, world");` from the controller would be nice. That's all that it needs to do; I will provide the rest.

If I can have that, I know that I can slot my app into it.

Comment: Hi @Mawg I've start a project hello world on intellij with office add in. I'll write the steps

Comment: I need it for AngularJS as an Outlook add-in from the toolbar, and all of the demos are fore something else, like Outlook from the Read or Compose panel, or MS, not Outlook, or they are not AnglaurJs (1.x) I am so frustrated, because this should be so simple, but I just can't find the information :-(

Comment: Hi @Mawg see your inbox! If that help i'll write the answer. No worries it's not a malicious message

Comment: Sorry, but I don;t see any email. Did you reply to my email?

Comment: needangularjshelp@gmail.com

Comment: I am sorry, but I just checked Gmail and don't see anything, even when I look at "all mail". Did you reply to my email, or type the address?  It looks correct, though.

Comment: Yes i know gmail has blocked the message

Comment: Ok, then I will send you an email from my real address, and you can write to that :-)  Thanks a a1,000,00 for your help :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87994/discussion-between-emanuele-and-mawg).